# Secure ASP.NET Core against credential stuffing

Tags: asp.net-core, security, passwords, rate-limiting

ASP.Net Core has protection against brute force guessing of passwords, by locking the account after a fixed number of login attempts.

But is there some protection against credential stuffing, where the attacker tries a lot of logins, but always with different usernames? Locking the account would not help, since the account changes on every attempt. 
But maybe there is a way to lock an IP against multiple login-attempts or some other good idea to prevent credential stuffing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using velocity checks with redis, this is basically just throttling certain IPs. Also some fraudsters will also rotate IPs, you could also detect when logins are happening more frequently (say 10x the norm) and start to block all logins for that short window. I wrote a blog post detailing some of the above. The code is all in node, but I did give some high level examples of how we stop fraud at Precognitive (my current gig). I will continue to build upon the code over the next couple of months as I post more in my Account Takeover series.

https://medium.com/precognitive/a-naive-demo-on-how-to-stop-credential-stuffing-attacks-2c8b8111286a

Answer (score 1):

IP throttling is a good first step, but unfortunately it won't block a large number of modern credential stuffing attacks. Tactics for savvy credential stuffers have evolved over the past few years to become more and more complex.

To be really effective at blocking credential stuffing, you need to be looking at more than IP. Attackers will rotate IP and User-Agent, and they'll also spoof the User-Agent value. An effective defense strategy identifies and blocks attacks based on real-time analysis of out-of-norm IP and User-Agent activity, plus additional components to enhance specificity (such as browser-based or mobile-app-based fingerprinting).

I wrote a blog post looking at two credential stuffing attacks in 2020, which I call Attack A (low-complexity) and Attack B (high-complexity).

Attack A, the low-complexity example, had the following characteristics:

- ~150,000 login attempts
- 1 distinct User-Agent (a widely used version of Chrome)
- ~1,500 distinct IP addresses (85% from the USA, where most of the app users reside)

Attack B, the high-complexity example, had the following characteristics:

- ~60,000 login attempts
- ~20,000 distinct User-Agents
- ~5,000 distinct IP addresses(>95% from USA, >99% from USA & Canada)

You can see that with Attack A, there were about 100 login attempts per IP address. IP rate-limiting *may* be effective here, depending on the limit.

However, with Attack B, there were only 12 login attempts per IP address. It would be really hard to argue that IP rate-limiting would be effective for this scenario.

Here's my post with more in-depth data: https://blog.castle.io/how-effective-is-castle-against-credential-stuffing/

Full disclosure: I work for Castle and we offer an API-based product to guard against credential stuffing.